# Lambda custom authorize, how to return custom message?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, lambda-authorizer

i'm using serverless-framework, node.js and typescript for my service. I have a custom authorizer where I fetch from external service some data and depending on the response from that service I want to return such an error code in my lambda.

The problem is that each time the response from the authorizer is (no matter how I return the error and what error and what status code it passes):

```
{
  "statusCode": 403,
  "error": "Forbidden",
  "message": "No principalId set on the Response"
}
```

Is this the specifics of the custom authorizer and nothing else can be returned or is it possible to modify the response somehow?

serverless.yml

```
...
functions:
  users:
      handler: lambdas/users/handler.main
      events:
        - http:
            path: /users
            method: GET
            private: true
            authorizer:
              name: customAuthorizer
              resultTtlInSeconds: 0
  customAuthorizer:
      handler: lambdas/custom-authorizer/handler.handler
      environment:
        APP_NAME: ${env:APP_NAME} 
   ...
```

and this is a simply code from my handler

handler.ts

```
export async function handler(event: APIGatewayTokenAuthorizerEvent, context: Context): Promise<any> {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
  try {
    if (!event.authorizationToken) {
      throw new HttpError("Unauthorized", 401);
    }

    const hasAccess = await fetchingPolicyFromExternalService(event.authorizationToken);
    if (!hasAccess) {
      throw new HttpError("Forbidden", 403);
    }

    const policyDocument = generatePolicy(event, "Allow"); //generate policy for Allow user to invoke api

    return policyDocument;
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof HttpError) {
      return {
        statusCode: error.status,
        body: error.message,
      };
    }
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: "UnknownError",
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding private: true

> Clients connecting to this Rest API will then need to set any of these API keys values in the x-api-key header of their request. This is only necessary for functions where the private property is set to true.

https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/

Not sure how you're sending your request, but consider this part. It could be that you're missing header information and that is why it always answers like that (i.e not your authorizer, but your function is protected). Therefore this response may come from your function, not the authorizer.